# Continuous and tempered $\Rightarrow$ bounded by a polynomial?

Tags: functions, continuity, distribution-theory

If $f$ is a continuous function that is moreover in the space of tempered distributions, is it true that $f$ is necessarily bounded by a polynomial function?

Comment: I'm thinking of $f$ as a sequence of very tall triangles over very small bases going out to infinity, hmm ...

Comment: But then, can you be at the same time tempered and such that the supremum growths faster than any polynomial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementing the idea of @zhw and at the same time answering the comment of @Goulifet:

Take a piecewise constant function 
$$f=\begin{cases}e^n,&x\in[n-e^{-2n},n+e^{-2n}]\quad n\in \Bbb N,\\0,&\text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$
Clearly, it belongs to $L^1(\Bbb R)$, hence it is tempered.

Now make it continuous - instead of rectangular bumps use triangular ones of the same height over the same base. The function is still $L^1$ (hence tempered), continuous, but it is not bounded by a polynomial.

Comment: @user1952009 I am not sure what you want to say by this comment.

Comment: If $f \in L^1_{loc}$ then $\varphi \mapsto \langle f,\varphi \rangle$ is a tempered distribution iff $F(x)= \int_{-x}^{x} |f(t)|dt$ is bounded by a polynomial

Comment: @user1952009 ok, how does this result contradict or support my solution? I don't see the relevance here. Perhaps you wanted to post it as a comment to the initial question?

Comment: @TZakrevskiy, I agree with your counterexample. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user1952009 if I understand you give a characterization of tempered functions in $L_{loc}^1$. Do you have a reference for this interesting result?

Comment: @Goulifet I'm not sure anymore this is necessary. Look at $\int_0^t f(u)du$ and assume it is bounded by a polynomial even if $\int_0^t |f(u)|du$ is not